# Looking for a film where the demon whistles

Tags: identify-this-movie

I am trying to find a film that I saw about 10 years ago (maybe a little less than that).
I thought Wesley Snipes was the main character, but I checked IMDB and couldn't find it in his filmography :/

Here are the things I remember:

- It was made some time in the 90s or possibly early 00's
- There is a demon that uses people as a host, so it randomly jumps from one body to another
- The person that the demon jumps into always whistles a tune
- I THINK the main character was a cop
- It's American
- > I remember at the ending of the film the main character and the demon (who is in the main characters friend or partner) are at a cabin or some other place in the woods and there is a confrontation.

Can anyone help me with this film please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for [Fallen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallen_(1998_film)) *(1998)*

[image]

The demon is played by various actors most memorable of which is [John Goodman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Goodman) in the final confrontation at the cabin where he behaves exactly as you describe. He portrays a sadistic demon that keeps whistling 'Time is on my Side' while jumping from person to person and performing murders and suicides.

The American detective you describe is played by [Denzel Washington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denzel_Washington).

Here's the trailer on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mth5u2PPFbY).